# Joomla database query 3.2

Tags: mysql, joomla

Hi I'm trying make query that logged user can get pokalista table 3 value of row.
Can't get it right help anyone ?

```
?php

$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest) 
{ 
    echo "<h2>Login first.</h2>"; 
}
else
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from($db->quoteName('fab_pokalista'));
    // it should pickup current login user username and return 3th value of row
    // name colum has same values that users real name
    $query->where($db->quoteName('name')." = ".$db->quote('$user->name .'));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadRow();
    echo "<h3>Hello:</h3><br />";
    echo $user->name . '<br />';
    echo "<h3>value of query:</h3>"; 
    print_r($row[3]);
}
?>
```

Comment: But do you need the value of 3rd column of each row or the full 3rd row of the resultset?

Comment: On a side note, you should use `#__pokalista` rather than `fab_pokalista` as you may decide to change the database table prefix at some point

Comment: What is that dot? $db->quote('$user->name .') And why do you have a variable name in quotes? That's going to treat it like a string `$usern->name .`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a quoting error in your `where` statement and an extra space and period, see the section in bold on the next line:

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('name')." = ".$db->quote( '$user->name .' ));
```

You're using single quotes around the variable reference `$user->name` if you want PHP to convert that to a value you need to either use double quotes " or you can remove them altogether.

***With double quotes***

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('name')." = ".$db->quote("$user->name"));
```

***Without quotes***

```
    $query->where($db->quoteName('name') . " = " . $db->quote($user->name));


<?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if ($user->guest)
{
    echo "<h2>Login first.</h2>";
}
else
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from($db->quoteName('fab_pokalista'));
    // it should pickup current login user username and return 3th value of row
    // name colum has same values that users real name
    $query->where($db->quoteName('name') . " = " . $db->quote($user->name));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadRow();
    echo "<h3>Hello:</h3><br />";
    echo $user->name . '<br />';
    echo "<h3>value of query:</h3>";
    print_r($row[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d get code working but the real issue was my table.
I’d made it using fabrik component and user plugin, in backend fabrik shows users username’s but real data in db is user id’s. 
Coding level=Noob
Appreciate for u help.
here is the code if someone someday need it

```
    <?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest)
{ 

echo "<h2>Login first.</h2>"; 
}
else
{
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from($db->quoteName('fab_tablename'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('name') .' = '. $db->quote($user->id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadRow();
echo "<strong>Hello:</strong><br />";
echo $user->name . '<br />';
echo "<strong>value of query 1</strong><br/>";
print_r($row[1]); echo "<br />";
echo "<strong>value of query 2</strong><br/>"; 
print_r($row[3]);echo"<strong>   €</strong>";
}
?>
```